# Should the question about Chase's 5/24 rule be reopened?

Tags: discussion, off-topic, closed-questions

Yesterday, this question was asked:

[How true is the Chase 5/24 limit on applications and which bureaus?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/86522/10997)

Today, the question was closed as "off-topic."

Is this really off-topic?  Why was this closed?  Should it be reopened?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion, this question should be reopened.

The question is about applying and getting approved for a credit card.  This is a subject that is most certainly related to Personal Finance and is something we cover every day here.  (The [credit-card](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/credit-card) tag is our 6th most popular tag.)

There was some concern in the comments that this question would be unanswerable.  I believe this question is very answerable, and I have done so.

I understand some negative reaction to the question, as there are people (myself included) who think it is unwise to acquire so many credit cards.  However, that doesn't make the question off-topic.

Remember, "too localized" is not a close reason, nor is "I don't like this question."  (That is what the downvote button is for.)  There are only five close reasons, and since this question is not off-topic, not too broad, not primarily opinion-based, not unclear, and not a duplicate, it should be reopened.

Comment: I've re-opened it for now as I agree with your analysis, but I'm open to re-closing it if a consensus forms the other way.